# MongoDB How to get value from subdocument when field name is unknown

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get data from one or more subdocuments but I don't know the name of the field that will hold the subdocument. Here are some examples of what the documents look like.

1. https://github.com/vz-risk/VCDB/blob/master/data/json/0C5DE044-B9B4-408D-9E65-D367EED12AB2.json
2. https://github.com/vz-risk/VCDB/blob/master/data/json/064F5887-C2DA-4139-B3AA-D55906F8C30A.json

I would like to get the action varieties for these incidents, so in the case of the first one I would like to get action.malware.variety and action.social.variety. In the second example it would be action.hacking.variety and action.malware.variety. So the problem is that I don't know what field is going to hold the subdocument. It could be one of hacking, malware, social, error, misuse, physical, and environmental.

So I would like to $unwind that field and do some stuff with the key name. Is this something that can be done with aggregation or do I need to switch over to mapReduce?

Comment: It is difficult to do using aggregation framework as you can only unwind object arrays. In the sample json, action attribute is just an object but not object array. So unwind can't be done here. Will it be ok if the schema is restructured? Also tell me how would you really want the output to be displayed.

Comment: This was actually a fair question as not everyone is aware of the uses for $ifNull and $cond in aggregation projection

Comment: @cj0809 you might want to look at the accepted answer which demonstrates working with the problem you observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be talking about a case where you are not sure if all of the hacking, social or malaware parts are there right. I think you want [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) first using the [$ifNull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator as in:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
    {$project: 
        { 
           hacking: {$ifNull: ["$action.hacking.variety",[null]]},
           social: {$ifNull: ["$action.social.variety",[null]]},
           malware: {$ifNull: ["$action.malware.variety",[null]]}
        }
   },
   {$unwind: "$hacking"},
   {$unwind: "$social"},
   {$unwind: "$malware"}
])
```

That should give you documents with something in each of those values.
Sort of pretty much the same with any of your possible list of values.