# Searching for field in MongoDb when exact path is unknown

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in Mongo where the structure is known.
It consists of

```
{
    "_id" : "123456__data",
    "fields" : {
        "field1" : {
            "type" : "boolean",
            "writeAccess" : "someWriteAccess",
        },
        "field2" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "writeAccess" : "secondWriteAccess",
        },
        "field3" : {
            "someConcretePermissionOperation" : "set",
            "writeAccess" : "thirdWriteAccess",
        }
    }
}
```

Now I got to find all documents, and preferably, all concrete values of "someConcretePermissionOperation", while the "field1", 2, 3 can be up to the user. That is, in different documents they could have different names. The only thing I know is the constant depth - if someConcretePermissionOperation will appear it will be under `fields.XXX.someConcretePermissionOperation`, where XXX can be anything.

Anybody got any ideas?

Just found something close to what I am looking for:

```
var operationOptions = [ "push", "set", "pushUnique" ];
db.mytable.aggregate(
   [
     { $redact:
         {
            $cond:
               {
                 if: { $gt: [ { $size: { $setIntersection: [ "$someConcretePermissionOperation", operationOptions ] } }, 0 ] },
                 then: "$$DESCEND",
                 else: "$$PRUNE"
               }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

But receiving 
`uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: NULL",`

Don't exactly know yet how to write "if exists, otherwise disregard" in this aggregation query.

Comment: See this [How to get value from subdocument when field name is unknown][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542307/mongodb-how-to-get-value-from-subdocument-when-field-name-is-unknown

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)** operator to check if the field is either not an array or not present:

```
var operationOptions = [ "push", "set", "pushUnique" ];
db.mytable.aggregate(
   [
     { $redact:
         {
            $cond:
               {
                 if: { 
                    $gt: [ 
                        { 
                            $size: { 
                                "$ifNull": [
                                    { $setIntersection: ["$someConcretePermissionOperation", operationOptions] },
                                    []
                                ]
                            } 
                        }, 
                        0 
                    ] 
                },
                 then: "$$DESCEND",
                 else: "$$PRUNE"
               }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```